# Infinispan Soft Index File Store OutOfMemoryError after upgrade to 10.0.1.Final

Tags: java, infinispan

After updating Infinispan from version 9.4.11.Final to 10.0.1.Final the starting of multiple caches produces this error when trying to start the fourth cache. With the previous version it runs smoothly.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
    at com.metaproc.core.datagrid.impl.InfinispanDatagridServiceImpl.<init>(InfinispanDatagridServiceImpl.java:139) ~[?:?]
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Error starting component org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManager
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:555) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:561) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:344) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:240) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:1091) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:513) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:693) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:632) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.startCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:1024) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index.start(Index.java:75) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.SoftIndexFileStore.startIndex(SoftIndexFileStore.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.SoftIndexFileStore.start(SoftIndexFileStore.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.support.ComposedSegmentedLoadWriteStore.startNewStoreForSegment(ComposedSegmentedLoadWriteStore.java:258) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.support.ComposedSegmentedLoadWriteStore.start(ComposedSegmentedLoadWriteStore.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.lambda$startWriter$42(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:1304) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.startStore(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:1333) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.startWriter(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:1296) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.lambda$start$0(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.support.DelegatingPersistenceManager.start(DelegatingPersistenceManager.java:39) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.support.CorePackageImpl$1.start(CorePackageImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.persistence.support.CorePackageImpl$1.start(CorePackageImpl.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.invokeStart(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:587) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.invokeStart(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:584) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:561) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startDependencies(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:605) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.doStartWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.startWrapper(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:547) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl.access$700(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistryImpl$ComponentWrapper.running(BasicComponentRegistryImpl.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:344) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:240) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:1091) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:513) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:693) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:632) ~[?:?]
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.startCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:1024) ~[?:?]
```

We are using this configuration:

```
final SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder persistentStoreConfiguration =
        new SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationBuilder(configurationBuilder)
            .indexLocation(indexPath)
            .dataLocation(dataPath)
            .maxNodeSize(8192)
            .fetchPersistentState(true);

new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .locking()
    .isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ)
    .lockAcquisitionTimeout(30000)
    .useLockStriping(false)
    .transaction()
    .autoCommit(true)
    .completedTxTimeout(60000)
    .lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC)
    .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
    .notifications(true)
    .reaperWakeUpInterval(30000)
    .cacheStopTimeout(30000)
    .transactionManagerLookup(new GenericTransactionManagerLookup())
    .clustering()
    .cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC)
    .stateTransfer()
    .fetchInMemoryState(true)
    .hash().numOwners(2)
    .l1()
    .lifespan(-1)
    .memory()
    .size(1)
    .persistence()
    .passivation(true)
.addStore(persistentStoreConfiguration).build();
```

It looks like something of the configuration of the soft index file store is not correct anymore, I just cannot figure out what it might be. I tried to decrease the maxNodeSize, without any success. Can someone point me to the part where I need to adjust the configurations after the upgrade or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You need to highlight that this is not an ordinary out-of-heap-space error. Instead, the error is that your JVM cannot create more threads: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`. Search for that error with a search engine, that gives lots of results.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Okay, but that still just happens after the upgrade and I'd really like to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty certain this is caused by the SoftIndexFileStore being segmented and creating a bunch of extra threads. There should have been a WARN message logged to your console output stating something to that extent.

You can also read about this at [Upgrading Guide](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/upgrading/upgrading.html#store_defaults).

You can explicitly define the store to not be segmented by setting the `segmented="false"` attribute on your xml configuration. Since you are using programmatic configuration it would just be adding `.segmented(false)` to your code. [Source Reference](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/AbstractStoreConfigurationBuilder.java#L153)